# Implementing user roles into project using CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan, authentication

Okay, so I am trying to create a user role system into my project using a combination of Devise and CanCan. I know that this is a popular combination but after working through a half dozen half-completed tutorials I finally got something working, but am still having a problem.

Here's a description: Users can register and they can be either an Administrator, Worker, or Client. The option that they choose saves to the database as it should, but the problem comes in when I try to use these options in CanCan. Here's my code so you can see what I have so far:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, 
                  :subdomain, :first_name, :last_name

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false

  ROLES = %w[admin worker client]

  def role?(role)
    roles.include? role.to_s
  end
end
```

**role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments
end
```

**assignment.rb**

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

**ability.rb** (this is for CanCan)

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new #guest user

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end

    if user.role?(:worker)
      can :create, Project
      can :update, Project do |project|
        project.try(:user) == user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lists, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :messages, :dependent => :destroy
    belongs_to :user

    attr_accessible :title, :description
    validates :title,           :presence => true,
                                :length => { :minimum => 5 }
end
```

Those are all of my models. I have followed the tutorial here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan and made sure my code was the same, albeit changing the user roles, but I keep getting the same error:

[image: Rails error with CanCan]

I have `load_and_authorize_resource` in my projects controller and in my projects view I have:

```
<% if can? :edit, @project %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
<% end %>
```

Nothing's working right now. This is kind of urgent and I'm not all that experienced in Rails so I would be very grateful for any help or suggestions that any of you have. Let me know if you need to see any more of my code or would like to describe more what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: 3 things, First, in your user model try replacing `roles.include? role.to_s` with `self.roles.include? role.to_s`. Second, are your gems up to date? make sure you're using the latest versions and maybe just run `bundle update`. Third, I would suggest adding the rolify gem to the devise and cancan combo if you have time to refactor, because it's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the relationship between Users and Roles :)

On your user.rb

```
has_many :assignments
has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
```

And then user.roles will be define ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses! Rorra, I added that code and it got rid of the error. However, it seems that even though my user is an Admin (), and I have set the user role in the ability.rb to manage all, I can still not see the edit link. (using the same code in the ability.rb as above).

However, when I change the code to have `can :manage, :all` right after `user ||= User.new #guest user` which would mean that everybody on the site would have manage all permissions, I can see the edit link, so the problem lies somewhere within my `if user.role? :admin can :manage, :all` code

Comment: ok, so my answer deserves at least one vote :P Try to run the console (like **script/rails console**), and check that you user actually has the role admin. Probably you can do something like **User.where(email: "my_user_email_hear").first.role? :admin**, by doing that you are debugging if you user actually has the role or not, there is a good chance that the problem right now is that you user either doesn't have the admin role, or it has the admin role but its not being retrieved.

Comment: Of you deserve an vote up haha, sorry about that :) So I opened up the console and this is what I got: http://i.imgur.com/BT9GL.png. The role is saving in the database. I also replaced my code `if user.role? :admin` with yours `if User.where(email: "keenanpayne15@yahoo.com").first.role? :admin` and nothing changed. It's like the model for CanCan is unable to read the role, unless my syntax is off.... Thanks again for your help. I'm finishing up a final project this week and I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you run on the console: **User.where(email: "keenapayne15@yahoo.com").first.roles** and also **User.where(email: "keenapayne15@yahoo.com").role? :admin**, it seems that you user has an attribute called **role**, besides having an association to the **roles** tables, and that may be the issue that is confusing you because by looking at the role attribute, you believe that the user has the "admin" role, but actually he just have that on an unused column named role. So what I'm saying, is that you have a M:N relationship with Roles, and that you have a field as well named role.

Comment: Here's the result for the first one: http://i.imgur.com/BESpt.png, and the second one: http://i.imgur.com/8yd6Y.png. I don't want this to associate to the database in any way, just to the constant array I'm declaring in my user.rb `ROLES = %w[admin worker client]`.

Comment: ok sorry, can you do this one: ** User.where(email: "keenapayne15@yahoo.com").first.role? :admin**, that will probably say "false" and that's the reason cancan is not setting the permissions for the admin.  If you don't want to associate the users to the roles, then why you have a model Role at all, and an inner model called "assignment" ?

Comment: Yeah, it came back as the same error as before. And I was just trying to follow the tutorials here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan and here http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association. Maybe I'll just try the whole thing over again, thanks again for your help man.